# How to make a function run at a particular time based on a field from firestore using flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm making an events app with an event model with a field called endTimeInMilleseconds, and I want to call a function as soon as that time occurs. I've been thinking about using various things like a Timer to make this happen, but I get stuck on trying to figure out how the app would know when the time is occurring at that moment and not when it has already passed when it is being parsed through. Would I need to use a stream to determine this or is there another solution that I'm not thinking of?

Comment: Take a look to firebase-functions and firebase-messaging, you can create functions triggered by firestore collection events or timers, and notify client flutter app to tirgger events on the app

Comment: I was thinking about making a cron job that would run every 60 seconds to iterate through the collection to see if the current time > endTimeInMilleseconds. But it seems like it would be kind of expensive to iterate through a list like that if it's long (unless it's not?) and was searching for another way.

Comment: Take a look at firebase documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events , you'll have different kinds of triggers that  One of that is scheduled functions https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions that may fit well to achieve what you want

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a straight forward way of doing this. I can think of a workaround that involves a secondary Cloud Function and Cloud Tasks, but I think it's the easiest way of achieving your purpose.

1. Create a Cloud Tasks' [queue](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-queues). It will keep the tasks that will eventually target your main Cloud Function.
2. Create a Service Account to execute the tasks. Grant it the role [Cloud Functions Invoker](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/iam/roles#cloudfunctions.invoker) at the main Cloud Function.
3. Create a secondary Cloud Function that triggers on [Firestore Events](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/cloud-firestore#event_types). I guess you're interested on the `create` and `update` events. Check [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions) if you are using Firebase Functions.
4. From this secondary Cloud Function [create a task](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-http-target-tasks#creating_http_target_tasks) on the created Cloud Tasks queue. That task will have to target your main Cloud Function and be scheduled to trigger at whatever time you want with the [`scheduleTime`](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2beta3/projects.locations.queues.tasks#Task.FIELDS.schedule_time) attribute. Make sure to provide the previously created SA so that it's the one triggering the tasks.

   The example in [here](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-http-target-tasks#creating_http_target_tasks) provides examples in different languages and sets up a timestamp so it should be fairly similar.

With the above setup, when a Firestore event is triggered, the secondary CF is executed, which creates a CT task that will run at the provided timestamp targeting your main CF.

While searching the right documentation I found [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/tutorial-gcf) that explains a similar setup but the tasks are created from GAE and it's strictly explained in NodeJS.